Gitlab CI, Merge Request Target Branch
In my pipeline, I'd like to have a job run only if the Merge Requests target branch is a certain branch, say release/1.0.0-rc or release/1.5.0-rc, etc.
Here is my job:
build-composer:
  stage: build-app
  image:
    name: $PHP_IMAGE
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - composer install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
    expire_in: 1h
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "dev" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^release\/.*$/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_STATE == "merged"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature\/.*$/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_STATE == "merged"'
      when: always

the attempt to merge the request from the feature/* branch to dev successfully triggered the pipeline to run after the merge. However, when merging from the dev branch to release/1.0.0-rc, no pipeline is triggered.
I've also tried changing =~ /^release\/.*$/ to == "release/**", but no luck.

This is because doing a merge event will not trigger a MR pipeline, as the docs explain:

This type of pipeline, called a merge request pipeline, runs when you:

Create a new merge request from a source branch that has one or more commits.
Push a new commit to the source branch for a merge request.
Go to the Pipelines tab in a merge request and select Run pipeline.


When you merge, the event triggering is a commit to the target branch. In your first scenario it worked with the dev branch because of the rule if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null'
What you're looking for is merged results pipelines, have a look at the docs on how to set those.

Thank you for ur answer, I'll look at the documentation in more detail in the future
